# Free software document management

Tags: linux, open-source, document-management

I'm looking for a personal or small business document management system.  I prefer free or open source solutions.  The commercial systems I've seen don't seem that relevant or easy to use anyway.  But the free solutions I see seem to be focused on academic or scientific niches.  Do you have any suggestions?

### Features that I'd like to have:

- work with PDF and txt documents
- input

  - manual
  - bulk
  - email
- indexing

  - OCR
  - custom metadata or attributes
- search
- workflow

  - rule-based processing
  - backups or mirror copies
  - pluggable notifications
- compatible with Linux and Macs

### Things I don't care about are:

- role based security
- dealing with Microsoft Offices files
- compatibility with Windows
- multi-level approvals

Comment: Is there any way in which storing files in an ordinary filesystem (and processing the PDFs with Tesseract to get an OCR-ed plain-text version of each PDF) wouldn't meet your needs? (Admittedly, I have no idea what you'd want to be notified of, nor what you want to accomplish with rules.)

Comment: @Kodiologist for me that would be e.g. searchability by tags. And from OPs requirements, e.g. input by email, rule-based processing, pluggable notifications.

Comment: I'm working on a more formal design document for this that I will use to solicit bids.

Comment: https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/The+Challenge+of+Managing+Your+Digital+Library/24326/ is talking about the same issue, but their idea of documents is much broader than what I'd initially try to handle.